# Conditional formatting from another cell

Tags: excel, format, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I would like to know how to conditionally control formats as below:

Cell "A" can have several different inputs. Depending on what, it gets colored formatted.

Cell "B" can have a value or not. If it doesn't have it it should stay unformatted.
If it has a value it should have the same color format as cell "A".

If cell "A" changes it should change the color format in cell "B" also, without changing the value in cell "B".

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do a search on "Conditional Formatting Excel 2010"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question - an example might help.

That said, [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format1_2007.php) is one tutorial on conditional formatting.

It may be slightly hairy, but I think you can do what you want.
Calculate formula based on $A1 and aqpply it to $A$1:$B$100

Answer (score 0):

IF the CF for ColumnA is applied with formulae then with fixed references for A ($A) the colours can be applied to ColumnB also where the Applies to ranges are A:B. The 'problem' may be only that there may be a trigger (ie a value) in a cell in ColumnA that is immediately to the left of a blank (ColumnB). For that case, apply an additional CF rule to ColumnB only (such as `=$B1=""` and ensure that has priority by checking Stop If True for it and placing it at the top of the list.