# Excel - Conditional Formatting. Referring to a styled cell instead of having fixed formatting

Tags: excel, dynamic, formatting, conditional-statements

I believe I'm asking the same question as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958864/conditional-formatting-from-another-cell) but it wasn't answered.

Here's my problem.

[image]

So, applied to the range `K3:K10`, I have several different conditional formatting rules that require a specific text string comprised of the contents of a referenced cell plus a constant text string. Each rule applies a different colour for a specific referenced cell and constant text string (DEAD or ALIVE) combination. For example, in the range, if a cell contains the word "Dog", then a space, and then the word "Dead", it will be formatted Red. The legend in columns `D` and `E` show what colours apply to each animal for the combination of criteria (Animal and Dead/Alive). What I want to do is, to be able to choose a colour for an animal with a drop down list in Column `C`, and have the CF use a lookup function or something to change the formatting of any of the cells within the range `K3:K10` based on the colour chosen in column `C`

So, if `K3` is "Dog Dead", then apply the same formatting as in cell `D3` or if it is "Dog Alive" apply the same formatting as `E3`. I don't want to just ask CF to make any cell containing "Dog Dead" red or "Dog Alive" light red, because the colour for dog might not be red. It could be green, or blue.

So, I guess I want dynamic condtional formatting. Is that right?

Thanks in advance,

Andy.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would require VBA, but I wouldn't know where to start. Any takers?

Comment: I've searched and searched with no luck but I'm sure this must be doable. I'm thinking something like creating a cell style and calling it to be applied to cells where the right conditions are met using vba when the sheet is activated. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: If this is not doable, can someone tell me. Cheers.